# Load website using Html-agility-pack using xpath-syntax

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm having this method to select out specific html and put it In a list.
Works perfect when I'm using a html-file saved on my computer. But how can a load a content from a website

This is my method loading the .html-file, witch works:

```
public void TestGetHtml()
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/laggen.html");
        var xpath = "//table[@id='tableSearchArticle']/tbody/tr/td[4]";
        var listOfGtins = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)
                       .Select(td => td.InnerText.Replace("GTIN:", ""));  
    }
```

But I want to load a website instead of a file, like this:

```
public void TestGetHtml()
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("http://www.dabas.com/mypages/search.aspx?typ=FP&sosokord=laggen"); <--- this is the site I want to load
        var xpath = "//table[@id='tableSearchArticle']/tbody/tr/td[4]";
        var listOfGtins = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)
                       .Select(td => td.InnerText.Replace("GTIN:", ""));  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.dabas.com/mypages/search.aspx?typ=FP&sosokord=laggen"); 
var xpath = "//table[@id='tableSearchArticle']/tbody/tr/td[4]";
var listOfGtins = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)
               .Select(td => td.InnerText.Replace("GTIN:", ""));
foreach (string gtin in listOfGtins)
{
    Console.WriteLine(gtin);
}
```

if you want to load HTML over HTTP from a URL.